# Win8 gets "bios has been reset" on every startup

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, bios, windows-update

recently i have had a periodically online windows update

and since then I have been geeting this message on almost each startup.

what should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is it before the Windows boot up? Then it may be caused by  dead BIOS battery. Try replacing it.

Comment: it a computer less than a year old. Can it be?

Comment: does it fit that it doesn't happen all the time?

Comment: Will you please edit your question to provide us more information about your configuration. Power supply can cause such issues. Have you tried to reset the bios on motherboard?